# Multiple if conditions in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command, batch-processing

I want something like this:- `if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 
&& %ERRORLEVEL% neq 255 GOTO Not closed by user` . But this syntax is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple if statements to simulate AND operator:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 255 GOTO :NotClosedByUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also do it like this :

> if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
>   if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 255 (
>   GOTO NotClosedByUser
>   )
>   )

So this can be easier to read, I think.